# How to I get the index of a TD in relation to the TABLE, not the TR

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have four tables on a page and I want to target the index of table cells in each separately, with the TABLE as the parent, not the ROW. This code returns the index within each row.

So I want to find the first three TDs with a class of "events" in each table.

```
$('.section .calendar').each(function(){  
 $(this).find('td.events').each(function(){
      ind= $(this).index()
      ind <= 2 ? $(this).css('background','#f90') : $(this).css('background','#000');

     })
  })
```

If I try:

```
ind= $('.calendar td.events').index(this)
```

it targets a cells' index within all four tables as the parent

```
ind= $(this).index()
```

targets the cells' index within each row(of all four tables) as its parent

The tables' structures are the usual valid :

```
<table class="calendar">
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td class="events"></td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="events"></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td class="events"></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="events"></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

(...etc)

- three more identical tables

Comment: Have you tried 'table .events'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.
Its basically calculating the number of TDs before the current one.

```
function getTDIndex($td) {
    var index1 = $td.prevAll("td").length;
    var index2 = $td.closest("tr").prevAll("tr").find("td").length;

    var index = index1 + index2;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the set of all tds as argument to index method :

```
$('.section .table').each(function(){  
 var childtds = $(this).find('td.events');
 childtds .each(function(){
  ind= $(this).index(childtds );
  ind <= 2 ? $(this).css('background','#f90') : $(this).css('background','#000');

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

RaraituL's above solution seems to work:

```
$('.section').each(function(){
 $(this).find('td.events').each(function(){
  var index1 = $(this).prevAll("td").length;
  var index2 = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").find("td").length;
  var index = index1 + index2;
  index <= 6 ? $(this).css('background','#f90') : $(this).css('background','#000');
 })
})
```